# Distribute a vector randomly in an R data frame column

Tags: r

I must be missing an obvious thing in R here.

I have a vector of say 
`vec = c("v1","v2","v3")` and I want to distribute this vector along a column in a data frame say

```
Girth   Height  Volume  newcolumn
8.3      70     10.3    V1
8.6      65     10.3    V2
8.8      63     10.2    V3
10.5     72     16.4    V1
10.7     81     18.8    V2
10.8     83     19.7    V3
11       66     15.6    V1
11       75     18.2    V2
10.8     83     19.7    V3
11       66     15.6    V1
11       75     18.2    V2
11.1     80     22.6    V3
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

We can use `rep` to make sure that it would also work if the number of rows is not a multiple of 3

```
df$newcolumn <- rep(vec, length.out = nrow(df))
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to somehow recycle values from `vec`.

`cbind` will do this, and produce your desired output

```
cbind(df, vec)
   Girth Height Volume vec
1    8.3     70   10.3  v1
2    8.6     65   10.3  v2
3    8.8     63   10.2  v3
4   10.5     72   16.4  v1
5   10.7     81   18.8  v2
6   10.8     83   19.7  v3
7   11.0     66   15.6  v1
8   11.0     75   18.2  v2
9   10.8     83   19.7  v3
10  11.0     66   15.6  v1
11  11.0     75   18.2  v2
12  11.1     80   22.6  v3
```

That said, your question title asks about "distribut[ing] a vector randomly".  To do that you'll need

```
set.seed(123)
df$newcol <- sample (vec, size = nrow(df), replace = TRUE)
   Girth Height Volume newcol
   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <chr> 
 1   8.3     70   10.3 v3    
 2   8.6     65   10.3 v3    
 3   8.8     63   10.2 v3    
 4  10.5     72   16.4 v2    
 5  10.7     81   18.8 v3    
 6  10.8     83   19.7 v2    
 7  11       66   15.6 v2    
 8  11       75   18.2 v2    
 9  10.8     83   19.7 v3    
10  11       66   15.6 v1    
11  11       75   18.2 v2    
12  11.1     80   22.6 v2
```

Comment: Exactly! what i neededThanks

Answer (score 2):

```
df$newcolumn <- vec

df

#>    Girth Height Volume newcolumn
#> 1    8.3     70   10.3        v1
#> 2    8.6     65   10.3        v2
#> 3    8.8     63   10.2        v3
#> 4   10.5     72   16.4        v1
#> 5   10.7     81   18.8        v2
#> 6   10.8     83   19.7        v3
#> 7   11.0     66   15.6        v1
#> 8   11.0     75   18.2        v2
#> 9   10.8     83   19.7        v3
#> 10  11.0     66   15.6        v1
#> 11  11.0     75   18.2        v2
#> 12  11.1     80   22.6        v3
```

This only works where the number of rows are a multiple of your vector length, taking advantage of vector recycling.

#### data

```
structure(list(Girth = c(8.3, 8.6, 8.8, 10.5, 10.7, 10.8, 11, 
11, 10.8, 11, 11, 11.1), Height = c(70L, 65L, 63L, 72L, 81L, 
83L, 66L, 75L, 83L, 66L, 75L, 80L), Volume = c(10.3, 10.3, 10.2, 
16.4, 18.8, 19.7, 15.6, 18.2, 19.7, 15.6, 18.2, 22.6)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))

vec <-  c("v1","v2","v3")
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>